# How do I add time to the current countdown clock using VB6 ? When I try to add additional minutes it reverts back to orignal time.

Tags: vb6, countdowntimer

This is a code snippet inside a loop. This is a countdown clock.

How do I add additional time to the countdown clock?

I don't understand why I can't just add additional minutes or hours
by saying "minutes = minutes + 20" for example. I am new at VB6. Sorry!

```
Dim time_now As Date
Dim hours As Long
Dim minutes As Long
Dim seconds As Long

time_now = Now

If time_now >= m_StopTime Then

    tmrWait.Enabled = False
    lblRemaining.Caption = "0:00:00" 'Time has reached 0. Boom!
Else
```

Here we divide the seconds into seconds, mins, hours

```
    seconds = DateDiff("s", time_now, m_StopTime)

    minutes = seconds \ 60
    seconds = seconds - minutes * 60
    hours = minutes \ 60
    minutes = minutes - hours * 60
```

Now we display the result

```
    lblRemaining.Caption = _
        Format$(hours) & ":" & _
        Format$(minutes, "00") & ":" & _
        Format$(seconds, "00")
```

end if

Comment: It's unclear what you're asking. Nowhere in your posted code do you attempt to add anything to anything else, and nowhere in the code you've posted is there a countdown clock. What specifically is the problem you're having?

Comment: Hi Ken. Sorry, I thought I had made the question clear. I finally figured out that I needed to use m_StopTime = DateAdd("h", 1, m_StopTime). This added 1 hour of time to my countdown clock. Thanks again for your time.